# Node MySQL is returning a slightly modified int

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am using node_mysql to query a 17 char long int from my MySQL database.
An example id would be `76561198185324675`.
My database field is a `bigint(17)`.

The id is **correctly** stored in the database. (I looked it up using the mysql-cli on my server.)

The problem is when I query the id like in the following example

```
db.query('SELECT `column` FROM `table`', function(err, res, fields) { });
```

res[0].column contains my id, but it is a wrong id. The returned id is somehow decreased by 5 in this example. It is now `76561198185324670` and no longer `76561198185324675` as stored in the database.

Edit: I tested it with a set of ids.
The last number of every id becomes `0` when I select it from the database.

Comment: One solution would be casting the result to a string and returning the string value:  `select cast(column as varchar(255)) as column from table`.  The string should be passed back correctly.

Comment: The [maximum safe integer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) in Javascript is 9007199254740991, which is substantially less than the numbers you're using. So converting to a string, like @GordonLinoff is suggesting, seems like the only solution to get it properly from the database.